# Sublime Text 3 Syntax & Preference Files

Tags: xml, svg, icons, sublimetext3

I recently created a customised theme for sublime text 3 and everything seems to be working pretty well except for the icons of some files in the sidebar. I have SVG sublime-syntax and tmPreferences files but for some reason my SVG file shows another icon instead.

Here is the code for the sublime-syntax file:

```
%YAML 1.2
---
name: XML (SVG)
hidden: true
file_extensions: ['svg']
scope: text.xml.svg
contexts:
  main:
    - include: scope:text.xml#prototype
    - include: scope:text.xml
```

Here is the code for the tmPreferences file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>text.xml.svg</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
      <key>icon</key>
      <string>file_type_svg</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: could it be due to the Package load order? and that the XML package / syntax definition also declares `svg` in its file extensions, and thus takes precedence over your SVG syntax? If you open an SVG file in ST, which syntax does ST open it with?

Comment: @KeithHall Indeed you are right: 'Packages/XML/XML.sublime-syntax'. How do i make my syntax take precedence ?